# Unable to create a map between a C++ vector and an object

Tags: c++, vector, maps, copy-constructor

I am trying to create a map between a particle and the location it is on. Essentially, I want my map `M[loc] = p` where `loc` is a `std::vector <int>` and `p` is a Particle.

This is the code that I have:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <map>
class Particle{
public: 
    std::vector <int> coords;                                        // the coordinates of the particles
    std::string ptype; 
    int orientation; 
    bool operator<(const Particle& rhs)const{
        return coords < rhs.coords; 
    }


    // constructor 
    Particle (std::vector <int> crds, std::string type_, int orientation_): coords (crds), ptype (type_), orientation (orientation_){

    }

    // destructor 
    ~Particle(){

    }

    Particle( const Particle &other); // copy constructor 

    // print location of the particle 
    void printCoords(); 

};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


  std::map <std::vector <int>, Particle> OccupancyMap;

  Particle p ({0,0,0}, "monomer", 0); 
  std::cout << p.ptype;
  Particle pdash = p; 
  OccupancyMap[p.coords] = pdash ;

}
```

when I try to compile this code, I get a massive error message:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:14:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:506:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string_view:175:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:643:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:677:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/tuple:1401:7: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Particle'
      second(_VSTD::forward<_Args2>(_VSTD::get<_I2>(__second_args))...)
      ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/utility:507:11: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::pair<const std::__1::vector<int>, Particle>::pair<const std::__1::vector<int> &, 0>' requested here
        : pair(__pc, __first_args, __second_args,
          ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:1684:31: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::pair<const std::__1::vector<int>, Particle>::pair<const std::__1::vector<int> &>' requested here
            ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                              ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:1562:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::vector<int>, Particle>, void *>>::construct<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::vector<int>, Particle>, const std::__1::piecewise_construct_t &, std::__1::tuple<const std::__1::vector<int> &>, std::__1::tuple<>>' requested here
                __a.construct(__p, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:1413:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::vector<int>, Particle>, void *>>>::__construct<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::vector<int>, Particle>, const std::__1::piecewise_construct_t &, std::__1::tuple<const std::__1::vector<int> &>, std::__1::tuple<>>' requested here
            {__construct(__has_construct<allocator_type, _Tp*, _Args...>(),
             ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__tree:2194:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::vector<int>, Particle>, void *>>>::construct<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::vector<int>, Particle>, const std::__1::piecewise_construct_t &, std::__1::tuple<const std::__1::vector<int> &>, std::__1::tuple<>>' requested here
    __node_traits::construct(__na, _NodeTypes::__get_ptr(__h->__value_), _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                   ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__tree:2139:29: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::vector<int>, Particle>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<std::__1::vector<int>, std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::vector<int>, Particle>, std::__1::less<std::__1::vector<int>>, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::vector<int>, Particle>>>::__construct_node<const std::__1::piecewise_construct_t &, std::__1::tuple<const std::__1::vector<int> &>, std::__1::tuple<>>' requested here
        __node_holder __h = __construct_node(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                            ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/map:1521:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::vector<int>, Particle>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<std::__1::vector<int>, std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::vector<int>, Particle>, std::__1::less<std::__1::vector<int>>, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::vector<int>, Particle>>>::__emplace_unique_key_args<std::__1::vector<int>, const std::__1::piecewise_construct_t &, std::__1::tuple<const std::__1::vector<int> &>, std::__1::tuple<>>' requested here
    return __tree_.__emplace_unique_key_args(__k,
                   ^
main.cpp:51:15: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::map<std::__1::vector<int>, Particle, std::__1::less<std::__1::vector<int>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::vector<int>, Particle>>>::operator[]' requested here
  OccupancyMap[p.coords] = pdash ;
              ^
main.cpp:35:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'other', but no arguments were provided
    Particle( const Particle &other); // copy constructor for some reason i dont know
    ^
main.cpp:26:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 0 were provided
    Particle (std::vector <int> crds, std::string type_, int orientation_): coords (crds), ptype (type_), orientation (orientation_){
    ^
1 error generated.
```

I don't quite understand what is going on here. What is the nature of the error here? What concept is it pointing towards?
I would appreciate any advice you have for me. I apologize if this is an obvious question.

Comment: It requires a default constructor for Particle, since `OccupancyMap[p.coords]` creates a default Particle before assigning.

Comment: or you can emplace the item instead... 
`OccupancyMap.emplace(p.coords, pdash);`

Comment: Thank you @S.M., that seemed to do the job